# animating a drawline in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

I wanted to animate a line on the view. Ex: A progressive line starting at (0,120) and progresses upto (100,120). I've already tried this with plain canvas.drawLine() but was unable to apply an animation while drawing a line. 
What I wanted to see is once the view is loaded a set of straight lines(of varying length) being drawn on the view. I don't want them as static lines. I wanted to see these lines when they are being drawn on the canvas.

I've tried couple of other options like, using the shape drawables and applying animations from the anim/xmls. Most of them didn't solve my problem. Extensive googling show the animations which are applied to the views directly. Here I dont want to create multiple image views as I'll end up having 6 lines on the view and i need to animate each of the line with different colors.

In future I should be able to move the lines up and down change there colors and do other kind of animations on each one of the lines.

Remembering the above constraints can you suggest me how to write a custom implementation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

well are you not just using canvas.drawline(...), or canvas.drawlines(...), Your View could have the variables which represent the lines, maybe an arraylist of Points or something.  I am currently trying to draw a line with moving values on a game I am making.  I simply just change the values put into the drawline function, and my line animates as those values change.  However it seams whenever the line has a slope closer to 1 my loop slow down and my other animations slow along with it.  Are you having a similar problem when animating the lines? or are you just not able to get them drawn?

Comment: the reason why my lines were slowing down my animation is because of various changes to the paints .setMaskFilter

Comment: Yep, keeping the points in variables is one good idea to take hold of the line drawn on cavnas. My main problem is I'm unable to do any animations while drawing lines.As I said earlier I wanted to see the animation of line being drawn on the canvas. I've achieved animation currently by calling invalidate() in the onDraw() method. But this solution seems to be very bad and sluggish. So, I'm currently in a state where I can draw lines and have a hold on the lines as points are stored in variables.But I'm unable to do some animations on the lines in an easy way.Invalidate() doesn't seems correct

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like your problem is in your game loop... I use a thread to loop through my draw and update methods, as I never was able to get the invalidate() thing working...

so below is a class called mainthread, it is created in your surfaceview in this case the surfaceview is called DrawView...

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {


// desired fps
private final static int    MAX_FPS = 75;   
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 0;    
// the frame period
private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  

// Surface holder that can access the physical surface
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// The actual view that handles inputs
// and draws to the surface
private DrawView gamePanel;

// flag to hold game state 
public boolean running;
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, DrawView gamePanel) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.doUpdate();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.doDraw(canvas);              
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.doUpdate(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
            }
        } catch(ClassCastException cce) {

        }finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}

}
```

using this thread it will call your update and draw methods approprietly, for onTouch just override the surfaceview (DrawView)'s onTouch method to access it normally. in order to stop the thread for what ever reason just set running to false.